# Poisson Distribution

Tags: histogram, poisson

I have a Poisson distribution that looks similar to the one below:

https://i0.wp.com/www.real-statistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/poisson-distribution-chart.png

I've been asked to find the mean, and then the three logical groups above and below the mean for a total of seven groups.

Were this a normal distribution where the min was 0, max was 12 and mean was 6, the logical groups might be:
-3: 1
-2: 2.666
-1: 4.333
0: 6
1: 7.666
2: 9.333
3: 11

But with a Poisson distribution (such as the image above), I would expect it to be more like:
-3: 0.625
-2: 1.25
-1: 1.875
0: 2.5
1: 4.25
2: 6.5
3: 10

Is there a faster way of looking for where these points would be than eyeballing it? I need to do this with more than a hundred histograms...

I apologize if I have the language wrong; this is my first time doing something like this.

Comment: This seems to be a better question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wasn't aware that existed, but will do for next time!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you need 7 bins that store the values you need.

For Poisson Distribution, the mean is the `lambda` itself, which in your case is 3. So `bin[3] = 3`

Consider the formula:

```
bins = []
for n = min to groups + min: # typically it is 0 to groups - 1
    bins[n] = min + range * n / groups
```

Now you need 2 different ranges:

1. n = 0 to 2, min = 0, max = 3, range = (3 - 0) = 3, groups = 3
2. n = 4 to 6, min = 3, max = 12, range = (12 - 3) = 9, groups = 3

You may apply the values in above formula to get your bins.

HTH. My memory is little out of practice, but I think general idea is correct.

> **Edit**: This might not work for Poisson distribution. Poisson is a Discrete type distribution while my solution works only for Continuous distributions. I will leave my answer here anyways.

Comment: I have modified my answer according to your question. If you need to access previous answer, check the edit history. Glad to help.